# Do real polarization and Kahler polarization of character varieties of closed surfaces give equivalent representations of the Mapping Class Group?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-field-theory, mapping-class-groups, character-varieties

This is a question about the Witten--Reshetikhin--Turaev representations of the mapping class group of a closed surface $\Sigma_g$.  For simplicity, we'll stick to the case $G=SU(2)$.

These representations are constructed as follows.  To a closed surface $\Sigma_g$, we associate the character variety $X=X(\pi_1(\Sigma_g),SU(2))$.  There is a natural line bundle $\mathcal L$ over $X$, whose curvature is a natural symplectic form on $X$.  We now let $Z(\Sigma_g,k)$ be a certain vector space consisting of sections of $\mathcal L^{\otimes k}$ over $X$.  There are various ways of constructing this vector space.

(1) The standard construction for the WRT invariants is to give a holomorphic polarization of $X$ (i.e. equip it with a Kahler structure), which depends on a choice of complex structure on $\Sigma_g$.  The space of holomorphic sections of $\mathcal L^{\otimes k}$ then forms $Z(\Sigma_g,k)$.  Given two holomorphic structures on $\Sigma_g$, there is a natural isomorphism between the corresponding spaces of holomorphic sections of $\mathcal L^{\otimes k}$, so we get a canonical vector space $Z(\Sigma_g,k)$, and an action of the mapping class group on it.

(2) Alternatively, one can use a "real polarization" of $X$ as in [this](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1204322) paper.  In this setting, one constructs a Lagrangian fibration $X\to B$ based on a decomposition of $\Sigma_g$ into pairs of pants, and the space $Z(\Sigma_g,k)$ consists of flat sections of $\mathcal L^{\otimes k}$ over the leaves of this fibration for which the monodromy of $\mathcal L^{\otimes k}$ is trivial.  In the reference given above, it is shown that the number of such fibers is the same as the dimension of the space of holomorphic sections from (1), so this $Z(\Sigma_g,k)$ has the "correct" dimension.  In this construction, the vector spaces associated to different polarizations can also be related by a natural isomorphism, the BKS pairing.  Thus there is a resulting representation of the mapping class group on $Z(\Sigma,k)$ here as well.

Question: are these two constructions equivalent in that there is a natural isomorphism between the two spaces I've called $Z(\Sigma_g,k)$ above?  Here "natural" means at least that the isomorphism is equivariant with respect to the action of the mapping class group.

Comment: There are 3-manifold invariants coming out of (2) which do NOT agree with the WRT 3-manifold invariants (see [this](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1231958) paper), though this is perhaps due to the construction of the canonical elements associated to handlebodies being different, not the quantization of the moduli space being different.

Comment: To my knowledge, holomorphic polarizations are related by the 'Hitchen connection' (further studied by Anderson and others) which is only projectively trivial, and so allows us to define only a projective action of the mapping class group.

Comment: In particular, they [push it to the limit](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.2635.pdf).